# Getting error with 'inherits' with node.js v5.10.1

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the following error when trying to run a simple script from the book Node.js in Practice.

I am not sure what is causing this error. I searched around the best I could to find an explanation, but I could not. does the util.inherit module not work in v5.10.1? Or am I missing something else? I am new to node.js.

```
~/node-project$ node index.js
util.js:786
    throw new TypeError('The super constructor to `inherits` must not ' +
    ^

TypeError: The super constructor to `inherits` must not be null or undefined.
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:786:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/byoungdale/node-project/countstream.js:6:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/byoungdale/node-project/index.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
```

index.js

```
var CountStream = require('./countstream.js');
var countStream = new CountStream('book');
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://www.manning.com', function(res) {
  res.pipe(countStream);
});

countStream.on('total', function(count) {
 console.log('Total matches: ', count)
});
```

countstream.js

```
var Writable = require('stream').Writeable;
var util = require('util');

module.exports = CountStream;

util.inherits(CountStream, Writable);

function CountStream(matchText,options) {
  Writeable.call(this, options);
  this.count = 0;
  this.matcher = new RegExp(matchText, 'ig');
}

CountStream.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
  var matches = chuck.toString().match(this.matcher);
  if (matches) {
   this.count += matches.length;
  }
  cb();
};

CountStream.prototype.end = function() {
  this.emit('total', this.count);
};
```

Comment: `Writeable` should be `Writable`, and you're probably good. (From some Googling it looks like some modules used `Writeable` in the past, but not any more.) Cheers.

Comment: The error just means that `Writable` is undefined - `inherits` works as it always did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. If this may work for you.

**var Writeable = require('stream').Writeable;**